# Finding the Z value of a point in a Triangle

Tags: c#, math

I have looked through stack overflow to try and find a solution and found a few things that did help a little but still not quite sure how to move forward with my problem or im just missing something really obvious!

If I have 3 points that define a triangle, each of these points has an XYZ, and then I have a point P that lies within the triangle, I only have the X and Y of point P, how do I go about finding the Z value of point P?

Ive had a look at things like Triangulation and Barycentric Coordinates but im not quite sure they fit the solution.

I am trying to implement this in C# and can provide more of an example if needed

Any help would be great please!

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points determine not only a triangle, but also a plane.

First [find the plane that passes through the three points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28geometry%29#Defining_a_plane_through_three_points), then use the equation of the plane to solve for the z-value of P.

Comment: Thank you for this! I never thought of thinking about it as a plane! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The formula you're after is

```
z = (z3(x-x1)(y-y2) + z1(x-x2)(y-y3) + z2(x-x3)(y-y1) - z2(x-x1)(y-y3) - z3(x-x2)(y-y1) - z1(x-x3)(y-y2))
  / (  (x-x1)(y-y2) +   (x-x2)(y-y3) +   (x-x3)(y-y1) -   (x-x1)(y-y3) -   (x-x2)(y-y1) -   (x-x3)(y-y2))
```

I think.

Answer (score 0):

Of your X,Y is in the same space as the X,Y,Z of the vertices - [find the plane equation](http://keisan.casio.com/has10/SpecExec.cgi?id=system/2006/1223596129) from the 3 points and then substitute the given X,Y and solve for Z.

Answer (score 0):

You know 2 of 3 values of the point you are looking for. You can simply use the formula (and reverse it) of the triangle to find your Z value (maybe using a projection matrix ;) ):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Further_formulas_for_general_Euclidean_triangles